# R- Confusion on what the level in predict function means

Tags: r, regression, prediction, confidence-interval

I used Excel to calculate the confidence interval on a predicted value, at 95% confidence interval, so to calculate `t-value` I used function `TINV(5%,6)` thats a 2.5% and 2.5% split on each side, where 6 is degree of freedom.

But in R, the predict function, when I give `level= 0.95`, I get a different interval range, however giving `level=0.975` gives me the same answer as excel.

So, seems like in predict when you give `level=0.975`, then it takes a split of 2.5% and 2.5% on each side

But all these websites, For [example](http://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-predict-new-data-values-with-r/), another [example](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/simple-linear-regression/prediction-interval-linear-regression), say we are looking for 95% confidence interval giving the formula level=0.95 (this would mean a 5% split on each side), but thats 90%, the level should be 0.975 for a 95% interval.

Whats going on? I am probabily getting confused.

---

EDIT:

`predict(model, data.frame(c= 12.75, p= 6, f=8), level = 0.975, interval = "confidence")`

The model here is a `multiple linear regression`

Data:

```
y <- c(85.10,106.30,50.20,130.60,54.80,30.30,79.40,91.00,135.40,89.30) # Total Sales

c <- c(8.50,12.90,5.20,10.70,3.10,3.50,9.20,9.00,15.10,10.20) # production cost

p <- c(5.10,5.80,2.10,8.40,2.90,1.20,3.70,7.60,7.70,4.50) # Promotion cost

f <- c(4.70,8.80,15.10,12.20,10.60,3.50,9.70,5.90,20.80,7.90) #First year box office

model <- lm(y ~ c + p + f)
```

Excel:

I have marked in yellow the forcasting in
[Excel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P591Bk1VTgZFdMcmkyeTA3WjQ/view?usp=sharing)

The problem is, with Excel I get forecast of 106.72 with upper 119.35 and lower 93.36 with `=tinv(5%,6)`

With R I get forecast of 106.72 with upper at 117.7 and lower at 95.65, `level=0.95`

With `level=0.975` I get exact values as Excel.

---

In Excel:

``` =tinv(5%,6) = 2.45``Variance =  5.46 ```

`106.72 +/- tvalue*variance` : `119.35` `93.36`

In R:

`se.ci <- predi$se.fit # Variance: 4.518`

`alpha <- qt((1-0.95)/2,6) # Value: -2.45`

`predi$fit[1] + c(alpha, -alpha) * se.ci # gives me 117.77165 95.65941`

As you can see the tstat value is the same but prediction is different.

But when I do this:

`alpha <- qt((1-0.975)/2,6) # Value:  -2.968`

I get `93.30182 120.12924` same as excel! (Using `level=0.975` in `predict` gets me the answer, hence the confusion)

Comment: How did you calculate the prediction intervals in Excel ? See my answer below. The intervals calculated using R are (of course) correct.

Comment: In excel, I calculated the variance and tinv value http://www2.cedarcrest.edu/academic/bio/hale/biostat/session19links/tinv.html which I am sure is correct, and used formula 106.72 +/-  tinv*variance.

Comment: Are you using the `T.INV` Excel function or `TINV` ? The two functions works differently.

Answer (score 1):

In simple linear regression the prediction interval for y for a given x* is:
[image]

where sy is given by:
[image]

Let us consider the following example:

```
df <- faithful
n <- nrow(df)
names(df) <- c("y","x")
mx <- mean(df$x)
sx <- sd(df$x)

mod = lm(y ~ x, data=df)
yhat <- predict(mod)

xnew <- 80
newdata = data.frame(x=xnew)

alpha <- 0.05
(ypred <- predict(mod, newdata, interval="predict", level = 1-alpha))

#### 95% Prediction interval #####
      fit      lwr      upr
1 4.17622 3.196089 5.156351
```

We can calculate this interval "by hand" using the formula given above:

```
SE <- sqrt(sum((df$y-yhat)^2)/(n-2))*sqrt(1+1/n+(xnew-mx)^2/((n-1)*sx^2))   
tval <- qt(1-alpha/2,n-2)
c(ypred[1]-tval*SE, ypred[1]+tval*SE)

#### 95% Prediction interval #####
[1] 3.196089 5.156351
```